# Metalsmith-collection not finding markdown files

Tags: handlebars.js, metalsmith

I have a static website using handlebars and metalsmith. I can create a `collection` called `carriers` from my metalsmith config file but the plugin `pattern` ignores the markdown files so `carriers` is always empty

My JS file has metalsmith config as follows

```
      ...//other metalsmith plugins
      .use(
        collections({
          carriers: { pattern: '**/*.md' }
        })
      )
      .use(markdown())
      .use(
        layouts({
          engine: 'handlebars',
          directory: './src/layouts',
          partials: './src/partials'
        })
      )
      ...//other metalsmith plugins
```

And my `carriers.hbs` contains the following

```
    <section id="carriers" class="integrations">
      <div class="cards">
        {{log collections}}
        {{#each collections.carriers }}
          <h5>{{this.title}}</h5>
        {{/each}}
      </div>
    </section>
```

The `{{log collections}}` Handlebars built-in helper logs this `{ carriers: [ metadata: undefined ] }` and the generated html file looks like this

```
<main>
  <section id="carriers" class="integrations">
    <div class="cards">

    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

So what am I missing here?

Comment: have you tried `*.md` instead of `**/*.md`?

Comment: yes, I played around with the pattern including `*.md`

Comment: I've create a simple example that works: https://repl.it/@JamesKhoury/BlaringNewParticles

Comment: There must be something you've left out that is different? Maybe the previous metalsmith plugins?

Comment: Oh thanks for the example! I believe it's either the project structure or the plugins. I'll look into it more

Comment: If you work it out could you come back and answer your question? Or at least lease some extra details?

Comment: Definitely! I'm actually still working on it.. haven't had time earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Update**
>   So I got more experience with Metalsmith and now got to know why the markdown files were not available. This is because of the `Metalsmith.source('my-directory')` did not contain the markdown files and they were in another folder.

---

Sadly, I don't have a solution for this because my project was too big to track down with my little experience in Metalsmith. However, the main points that I believe causing the problems and to watch out for are

1. Internationalization plugin structure is important to keep in mind how it works with other plugins
2. The order of plugins in the build process (e.g. `markdown()` must be before `layouts()`) otherwise you might get an error or unexpected outcomes
3. The pattern of the `collections` plugin